# How to indent text based on the level of heading in docx with Pandoc?

Tags: docx, pandoc

I convert AsciiDoc to Word via DocBook. The `db->docx` conversion is done with Pandoc and is the most interesting.

I provide a reference file with `--reference-doc`. I specified indentation for headings in the reference file. Now headings are indented. But the text is not:

[image]

While I want the text indentation to match the headings indentation:

[image]

However, from what I can see, all snippets of text under different headings have exactly the same style. I could provide styles manually in `adoc`, but this is tedious and error-prone. Is there a way to set proper indentation automatically?

Comment: ah, you found a solution :) https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6586#issuecomment-671935698

Comment: Oh, yeah, thanks for reminding, let me post it here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [a reasonable-ish solution](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6586#issuecomment-671935698). Let me also post it here:

I was able to work around the problem by manually editing `numbering.xml` in the reference .docx file.
There is a number of `<w:abstractNum>` sections with `w:abstractNumId` from 0 to 14 in it. During the analysis of the generated .docx I found out Pandoc generates its own `<w:abstractNum>` sections, but those are copied from the original sections with numbers 0, 11 and 14. I have no idea why. Anyway, I added a bunch of `<w:ind>` tags to `<w:abstractNum>` sections in the reference .docx and this solved the problem for me.